# My code is eliminating just few dates(rows)

Tags: python, database, pandas, date, google-colaboratory

Well I'm working on a large dataframe that has information from 1950 to 2019. To analize it I just want to focus on the information from 2000 to 2019. My code is eliminating just few dates.

`PGJ_dataframe.drop(PGJ_dataframe[PGJ_dataframe['FechaHecho'] < '2000-01-01'].index, inplace = True)`

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Try just `PGJ_dataframe = PGJ_dataframe[PGJ_dataframe['FechaHecho'] < '2000-01-01'].copy()`